# No output in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I try to print out text in information section, to plot graphs separately for cases and deaths of cover 19  and make a summary table for each month in summary section.
But now, only sidebar shows, text and graphs don't show up at all.
I guess there are mistakes in server.R
But,I check code several times and still have no idea what the problem is. Does anyone can help?

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data<-read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lingling1123/covid-19-data/master/us.csv')
data$date<-as.numeric(as.Date(data$date,origin='2020-01-21'))-18281
data$cases<-data$cases/1000
data$deaths<-data$deaths/1000
Jan<-c(1:11)
Feb<-c(12:40)
Mar<-c(41:71)
Apr<-c(72:101)
May<-c(102:132)
Jun<-c(133:162)
Jul<-c(163:193)
Aug<-c(194:224)
Sep<-c(225:254)
Oct<-c(255:285)
Nov<-c(286:298)



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(navbarPage('All you can know',

    # Information
    tabPanel('Information',
     mainPanel(
       textOutput("info"),
     )
    ),

    # Summaries
    tabPanel('Summaries',
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            h4('You can create plots using the radio buttons below.'),
            radioButtons('var',h5('Select the variable '),choices=list('cases','deaths')),
            h4('You can create numerical summaries below.'),
            selectizeInput("mon", h5('Select the month you want to check'),selected = "Jan", choices = c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct'))
        ),
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot"),
            tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {
  
   output$info <- renderPrint({
    print('For this project, I use Covid19 dataset that incluses date, cases and deaths to make a exposure notification app.')
  })
  
  
  
  
     value<-reactive({
         variables<-input$var
  })
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        if(value()=='cases'){
          ggplot(data,aes(x=date,y=cases))+geom_point()
        }else{
          ggplot(data,aes(x=date,y=deaths))+geom_point()
        }     
      }
      )
 
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the data load section from your `ui.r` to `server.r`, e.g.

`ui.r`

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(navbarPage('All you can know',

    # Information
    tabPanel('Information',
     mainPanel(
       textOutput("info"),
     )
    ),

    # Summaries
    tabPanel('Summaries',
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            h4('You can create plots using the radio buttons below.'),
            radioButtons('var',h5('Select the variable '),choices=list('cases','deaths')),
            h4('You can create numerical summaries below.'),
            selectizeInput("mon", h5('Select the month you want to check'),selected = "Jan", choices = c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct'))
        ),
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot"),
            tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)))
```

`server.r`

```
data<-read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lingling1123/covid-19-data/master/us.csv')
data$date<-as.numeric(as.Date(data$date,origin='2020-01-21'))-18281
data$cases<-data$cases/1000
data$deaths<-data$deaths/1000
Jan<-c(1:11)
Feb<-c(12:40)
Mar<-c(41:71)
Apr<-c(72:101)
May<-c(102:132)
Jun<-c(133:162)
Jul<-c(163:193)
Aug<-c(194:224)
Sep<-c(225:254)
Oct<-c(255:285)
Nov<-c(286:298)

shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {
  
   output$info <- renderPrint({
    print('For this project, I use Covid19 dataset that incluses date, cases and deaths to make a exposure notification app.')
  })
  
     value<-reactive({
         variables<-input$var
  })
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        if(value()=='cases'){
          ggplot(data,aes(x=date,y=cases))+geom_point()
        }else{
          ggplot(data,aes(x=date,y=deaths))+geom_point()
        }     
      }
      )
 
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I moved loading to server.r but still no graphs.